# What are the security benefits or risks of HTTP/2?

Tags: http, protocols, internet, risk, http2

Since HTTP/2 is starting to get adopted by more and more sites everyday. Are there any security benefits or known risks regarding HTTP/2?

Comment: Multiplexing should make traffic analysis slightly harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 7540 Section 10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-10) is a security consideration section that documents a number of security considerations when implementing and/or using HTTP/2. Briefly:

> - 10.1.  Server Authority
> - 10.2.  Cross-Protocol Attacks
> - 10.3.  Intermediary Encapsulation Attacks
> - 10.4. Cacheability of Pushed Responses
> - 10.5. Denial-of-Service Considerations
> - 10.5.1. Limits on Header Block Size
> - 10.5.2. CONNECT Issues
> - 10.6. Use of Compression
> - 10.7. Use of Padding
> - 10.8. Privacy Considerations

Most of the regular security considerations for HTTP/1 are also still valid, as HTTP/2 has the same application level semantic as HTTP/1.

Answer (score 2):

From a cryptographic point of view, HTTP/2 requires to support at least TLS1.2 which means the communication channel will be encrypted using AEAD ciphers i.e. state-of-the-art crypto.